# From Access, how do I open a Windows Explorer folder knowing only part of the folder name?

Tags: ms-access, vba, directory

My incomplete file path is stored in `Me!txtFilePath`. It contains a complete path to the folder's location and the first 9 out of ~30 characters of the folder name. Those first 9 characters are guaranteed to be unique. Currently I have a button that executes the code below when clicked:

```
    Shell "explorer """ & Me!txtFilePath & "", vbNormalFocus
```

How would I make sure it opens the right folder given that I don't have the last several characters of the folder name? Thanks!

edit: I am trying to open a network folder that I don't have a "drive" for.

Comment: You can use `Dir(Me!txtFilePath & "*")` to identify a matching file name.

Comment: Hm that's not working for some reason. It just opens windows explorer but  not to a specified file: `Shell "explorer.exe " & Dir(Me!txtFilePath & "*"), vbNormalFocus`. I know for sure the path before the * is there exactly cause I copy and pasted the file path and compared it to my outputted file path

Comment: Try `Shell "explorer " & "Me!txtFilePath" & "", vbNormalFocus`  or  `Shell "C:\Program Files\explore.exe " & Me!txtFilePath , vbNormalFocus` space inserted after your application location in the string passed to Shell

Comment: Explorer won't open with a partial folder name, because it can't find the folder to open on. Test it yourself by typing a name + a wildcard (eg., "C:\temp*") into the Explorer location bar; you get an error message that says `Windows can't find the folder "C:\Temp*"`.  @Tim had the solution, but you don't use it in the `Shell` command. You use it *first* in your code to find a folder that matches your partial name, and then you can pass the full name you found with that code into the call to `Shell`.

Comment: I tried that by declaring a string variable and setting it equal to `Dir(Me!txtFilePath & "*")` , but when I Debug.Print the string variable, it comes up as empty. And I know Me!txtFilePath gives a valid path..

Comment: Maybe the advice I was given is for files, whereas I'm trying to find and open a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why exactly this solution is the one that works for me whereas the suggestions did not, but I found the answer. Most of it was solved by the commenters to my original post - thanks to all of you.

Basically, I had to set a string variable equal to the `Dir` value. `Dir` only returns the ending portion of the folder name, not the entire path, so when opening the file I needed to combine it with the known beginning of the path name. I also had to use `Application.FollowHyperlink` instead of `Shell`. I don't know why and I don't know if there are any drawbacks. Maybe `Shell explorer` only works for files, not folders.

```
Private Sub btnJobFile_Click()
    Dim strStartFilePath As String
    Dim strEndFilePath As String

    strStartFilePath = "\\JobFolders" & Me!txtFilePath
    strEndFilePath = Dir(strStartFilePath & Me.JobNum & "*", vbDirectory)

    Application.FollowHyperlink strStartFilePath & strEndFilePath
End Sub
```